# How to add a document as a child of another document in a Roslyn project?

Tags: roslyn, visual-studio-sdk

In Roslyn, I can add a new document to a project like this:

```
var documentId = DocumentId.CreateNewId(currentProject.Id);

var newSolution =
    currentSolution.AddDocument(documentId, "myfile.cs", code);
```

Using the Visual Studio SDK, I can add a new file as a child of another file like this:

```
parentFileItem.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(newFilePath);
```

Where `parentFileItem` is the document - of type `ProjectItem` - under which I want to add the new file. And `newFilePath` is the path of the new file.

I want to be able to do a similar thing to a Roslyn solution. Is this possible?

If that is not possible, can I "move" an existing ProjectItem to become a child under another existing ProjectItem via the Visual Studio SDK?

That is, I will add the new document via Roslyn, and once changes are applied, I want to move the file created via Roslyn under another existing file.